# Test if components is exported and modules are imported by Angular 2 module

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I writing unit tests for all our modules in Angular 2. And I need to verify that all necessary modules are imported as well as all necessary components are exported from my modules. Anyone know how to write tests for this?

Comment: Did the answer help you? Please, consider marking it as correct or explaining what problems you encountered with it. This may help other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This presupposes matching against module decorator annotations, which can be retrieved in the same way they were defined, via `Reflect` metadata.

Considering that there is only one decorator on module class, `NgModule`, it should be:

```js
import { AppModule } from '…';
import { SomeModule, SomeComponent } from '…';

// …

const appModuleAnnotation = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', AppModule)[0];

expect(SomeModule).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
expect(appModuleAnnotation.imports.includes(SomeModule)).toBe(true);

expect(SomeComponent).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
expect(appModuleAnnotation.declarations.includes(SomeComponent)).toBe(true);
```

Comment: I want to test all my module code which is not a bootstrap module (angular 4). is there a way i can mention include all/one of them dynamically loaded modules

Comment: @AniruddhaDas I'm not sure what you mean. If you need to test what's specified in @NgModule `import` and `export` properties, it's like the answer explains. If your case is different, consider asking a new question that explains your case.